# Replace 3-way light with ceiling fan

Tags: switch, ceiling-fan

Trying to install a ceiling fan to replace a bedroom light that's currently on a 3 way switch. I'd like to leave the ceiling fan light on the 3 way switch, and then have one new single switch for the fan. Can I just run an additional 14/2 from the wall switch box where the power comes in- to the fan, and then add a fan switch to that location? And just leave the current 3 way switch the way it is? Obviously I'll have to switch to a 2-gang box.

Thanks!

EDIT: Added new, clearer pictures of the two boxes.

[image: Box 1]

[image: Box 2]

Comment: Possibly yes, but the devil is in the details. Have you opened up the switch box on the wall and/or the light on the ceiling to see what the existing wiring looks like?

Comment: I've opened the light on the ceiling and it just has the hot, neutral, and ground wires (white, black, and copper). Haven't opened up the switch yet, what should I be looking for?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to identify which switch power comes into, and whether the other 3-way is a spur/loop, or whether power is inline through the 2nd switch.  If the latter, only a smart-switch solution will be legal.  Either way, you need to *replace* the switch-fan cable with a /3, not add to it with a /2.  All related conductors must be in the same cable NEC 300.3.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please?

Comment: Edited the original post with pictures!

Comment: There's a _lot_ of wire in the back of that box! With the power off, carefully uncoil it, scrape some of the paint/plaster off of it so you can determine wire colors, and identify which wire comes from which cable. You may already have a /3 cable heading to the ceiling box which means you would already have everything you need to wire the fan & light without running anything new. Include new pics once you've done that. Also, a pic of the existing wiring at the light in the ceiling would help us _and_ you before you take it apart.

Comment: Added more pictures of the box with all the wires! Sorry they're not the best, trying to do this project for my mom and it's the best that she's sent me, won't be at her house for a few days. Looks like there's 3 Romex in that box. Had the ceiling box open last week, it's definitely just a black, white, and ground.

Comment: @Bemercleg what make/model of fan were you planning to use, and were you planning to put a light kit on it, or install separate lights?

Comment: Not sure the specific make and model, but a fan with a light kit. Ideally with the light kit left on the 3 way switch, and a new switch for the fan.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Edited the post with some clear pictures I was able to take today.

Comment: *Ideally with the light kit left on the 3 way switch, and a new switch for the fan.* Actually, that may not work. Many fan/light combos use a shared neutral for the fan and the light, which won't work if you've got switched hots each with their own paired neutral.

Comment: I should add that the light doesn't NEED to be on a 3 way switch... They're only a couple feet from each other. So I could cap off one box. But if I go to a single pole for the light it needs to be the box that currently has 2 romex in it, since that's by the door.